# how do I activate the dash to display feeds from my online accounts in the social media lense?

Tags: unity, 13.04, unity-dash, lenses, gwibber

Just upgraded to 13.04. I was hoping that the dash would replace gwibber, but I cannot even see my facebook or twitter accounts in the social media lense.  All my online accounts are there, but nothing is showing up for an option for the unity dash, unless I'm looking in the wrong spot of coarse....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how, it was my mistake.  In settings>privacy>search results I had online search results shut off.  I turned it on and now it working fine again.  I had it turned off because I can not stand shopping results cluttering my search for files on my computer.  If I want to go shopping I'll go to a website.